# ASCII Code to NSData

Tags: objective-c, ascii

I'm trying to figure out ESC/POS commands and I need the code "GS" (ASCII code 29) put into NSData.

Currently I can put the strings I want to print without problems using the code:

```
NSString *str = @"Text I want to print";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Is there any easy way to do that using either C++ or OBJ-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C, C++, and Objective-C let you put arbitrary ASCII codes into a string using so-called *escape sequences*.

Escape sequence start either in `\x` followed by two hex digits, or `\0` followed by three octal digits.

ASCII `GS` is 29 in decimal or `1D` in hex, so you can put an `GS` in an `NSData` like this:

```
NSData *data = [@"\x1D" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: you .. are .. awesome.., been trying to find out for like hours... thanks!